Is there a way to have react native tab bottom navigation to be shown in other pages outside of the (tab) route group?
I want the tab bar to be shown on all the pages I want, simultaneously, do not want the route added to the tab bar items. Only the 4 pages I have added inside the (tab) route group should be visible inside the tab bar
